# Empty result for Db4o queryByExample() method when I specifiy a Class

Tags: java, class, dynamic, classloader, db4o

So I'm having a strange problem with the Db4o API. I'm trying to retrieve certain classes of objects (depending on a user's query, but that's not really relevant), from a database. The database *definitely* has objects with the classes I want to retrieve. So for example, when I queryByExample() for just any Object, and then print out the Classes of each element of the object set, like so...

```
public void evaluateQuery(ObjectContainer db) {
    if (this.hasPredicate) {
        ;
    } else {
        if (this.isNode) {
            ObjectSet nodes = db.queryByExample(Object.class);
            ListIterator listIter = nodes.listIterator();
            while (listIter.hasNext()) {
                Object node = listIter.next();
                System.out.println("Object has Class: " + node.getClass());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and I get a result like this...

```
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class Node
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
Object has Class: class SubNode
```

...As you can see, the database has object with Classes set to Node and SubNode. Now, I'd like the code to actually work like this...

```
public void evaluateQuery(ObjectContainer db) {
    if (this.hasPredicate) {
        ;
    } else {
        if (this.isNode) {
            ObjectSet<Node> nodes = db.queryByExample(Node.class);
            ListIterator<Node> listIter = nodes.listIterator();
            while (listIter.hasNext()) {
                Node node = listIter.next();
                System.out.println("Object has Class: " + node.getClass());
            }
        }
    }
```

.. but when I do this, the ObjectSet is invariably empty, and I can't seem to figure out why. I load a certain subset of Classes, such as the above Node Class, into the environment with ClassLoader at runtime, and they're definitely in there, as I instantiate/use them in other contexts with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a package import problem. For some reason when using db4o to say...

import com.db4o.*;

doesn't resolve dependencies that saying....

import com.db4o.query.Predicate.

...does. Strange....

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct query counterpart. It will retrieve all instances of the given class. And it interacts also better with Java generics =)

```
List<Node> nodes = db.query(Node.class);
// do stuff
```

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Can you provide a link to a fully working example which shows this issue?